Confused about JSON and Array in TypeScript
I get data from the database with Sveltekit and nodejs and always fetching data like that
...
responseData = await response.json();

It returns Object and I can assign it to an array
let getData = [];
getData = responseData ;

What makes me confused is why the returned JSON Object display at console have the bracket which should be an array.(but it is Object checking with typeof)
[
 {a:1,b:1},
 {a:2,b:2},
]

What i expect of a JSON Object should look like
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}
and why the JSON Object can be assigned to an array directly?
I guess I have some misunderstanding about these data types.

Arrays are objects. And you're not assigning anything to an array. You're assigning to a variable. You can assign anything to a variable.

“Top level JSON arrays” are legal in JSON. link

Your responseData is typed as any which TypeScript has no problem assigning to an existing variable of type any[]

The result of awaiting response.json() is currently defined as type any, which is not so much a type as a way of telling TypeScript "don't worry what type this is". This means not only can you assign any value to a variable of type any, you can also assign a value of type any to a variable of any type, which may be surprising. (It is generally preferable to use the type unknown in cases like this, for what it's worth -- you need to explicitly cast unknown values to some other type before you can do much with them.)
typeof [] is "object", so you cannot use typeof to distinguish arrays from objects. Use Array.isArray(x) to check for an array instead. (Beware that typeof null is "object" as well, if you haven't encountered that one.)
It is considered valid for JSON to be an array at the top level. In some contexts, any JSON-compatible value including strings and numbers etc. may be accepted as the top-level value, but this is generally avoided.
